# Minify Webpack chunk names

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify, bundling-and-minification

After doing its thing, WebPack outputs what seems to be a chunk-resolution manifest, which looks like this:

```js
window.__JS_CHUNKS__ = {
 "@ourcorp/coupon-pages~._node_modules_@ourcorp_coupon-pages_src_c": "@ourcorp/coupon-pages~._node_modules_@ourcorp_coupon-pages_src_c.eaabef68ce.js",
 "containers/DigitalCouponsContainer~._node_modules_@": "containers/DigitalCouponsContainer~._node_modules_@.45aea662bd.js",
 "@ourcorp/example-single-route~._node_modules_@ourcorp_example-single-route_src_c": "@ourcorp/example-single-route~._node_modules_@ourcorp_example-single-route_src_c.3e7438a4fb.js",
 "@ourcorp/meal-planning-ui~._node_modules_@ourcorp_meal-planning-ui_dist_i": "@ourcorp/meal-planning-ui~._node_modules_@ourcorp_meal-planning-ui_dist_i.fd270269e2.js",
 "routes-LandingPage-LandingPageConnector~._node_modules_@": "routes-LandingPage-LandingPageConnector~._node_modules_@.21b70c9545.js",
 "routes-MyListPage-MyListPageConnector~._node_modules_@": "routes-MyListPage-MyListPageConnector~._node_modules_@.1028dc74cb.js",
 "routes-MyPlansPage-MyPlansPageConnector~._node_modules_@": "routes-MyPlansPage-MyPlansPageConnector~._node_modules_@.c1d664a6be.js",
 "routes-MyRecipesPage-MyRecipesPageConnector~._node_modules_@": "routes-MyRecipesPage-MyRecipesPageConnector~._node_modules_@.650d63811e.js",
 "routes-PlanDetailPage-PlanDetailPageConnector~._node_modules_@": "routes-PlanDetailPage-PlanDetailPageConnector~._node_modules_@.34ec62e971.js",
 "routes-RecipeCategoryPage-RecipeCategoryPageConnector~._node_modules_@": "routes-RecipeCategoryPage-RecipeCategoryPageConnector~._node_modules_@.948bfcf4a1.js",
  // many more omitted for brevity
}
```

These strings seem very long and repetitive, and while gzip takes care of that for network, I’d like to lessen JavaScript parse/evaluate time after decompression, too.

I have some ideas on abbreviating these strings, but Webpack’s documentation is unclear on how the chunks are resolved using this object, so I’m sure I’m missing some ideas or about to break something.

- Abbreviate `ourcorp` to `o` or something
- Abbreviate `_node_modules_` to `//` or something unlikely to clash with future Webpack syntax
- Use Base64 chunk hashes with the shortest character length unlikely to clash
- Reference property name strings in the property value, if the value contains the property name. For example,

  ```
  "containers/SearchGrids~._node_modules_@": 
    "containers/SearchGrids~._node_modules_@.26b7dbe62b.js"
  ```

  would become

  ```
  "containers/SearchGrids~._node_modules_@": "#.26b7dbe62b.js"
  ```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this object is generated from webpack itself. Typically you can read the [webpack stats object](https://webpack.js.org/api/stats/#structure) to view what bundles were generated and why.